# Remover registros duplicados do array do select php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Não consigo remover registros duplicados no array

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos order by Data asc");
$query -> execute();
$ContCampos = $query -> rowCount();

$consulArray = array();

while($consulta = $query ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $consulArray[] = array_unique($consulta);

}

foreach($consulArray as $copia1)
{
    $nome = $copia1['Nome'];
        echo '<option>'.$nome.'</option>';

} 

print_r($nome);
```

Fiz a busca no BD, e preciso que retorne a data e o nome, porém não retornar dados duplicados! tem a opção de usar o select distincs mas não queria utiliza-lo! 
Não sei pq o array_unique não está filtrando, se alguém poder me ajudar!

Resultado do Select

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 83 [Nome] => Ana Carla Pagung [Verdura] => QUIABO [Quantidade] => 2 [Observacao] => [Unidade] => KILOS [Data] => 2018-05-07 ) 

[1] => Array ( [id] => 84 [Nome] => Ana Carla Pagung [Verdura] => QUIABO [Quantidade] => 25 [Observacao] => [Unidade] => CAIXAS [Data] => 2018-04-05 )
```

Comment: dentro do array tem algum valor que seja unico do registro? tipo um ID? Você vai utilizar apenas o nome igual no exemplo?

Comment: Coloquei o resultado do print_r, preciso no caso a Data e Nome que está no array

Comment: Então no caso não tem valores iguas, são requisições diferentes, porem da mesma pessoa

Comment: vc quer fazer exatamente o que? exibir o que?